# Running even basic SQL queries on a >60 GB table in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I am running MariaDB on a vServer (8 CPU vCores, 32 GB RAM) with a few dozen database tables which aggregate data from external services around the web for efficient use across my collection of websites (basically an API layer with database caching and it's own API for easy use in all of my projects).

All but one of these database tables allow quick, basic queries such as

`SELECT id, content FROM tablename WHERE date_added > somedate`

(with "content" being some JSON data). I am using InnoDB as the storage engine to allow inserts without table locking, "id" is always the primary key in any table and most of these tables only have a few thousand or maybe a few hundred thousand entries, resulting in a few hundred MB.

One table where things don't work properly though has already >6 million entries (potentially heading to 100 million) and uses >60 GB including indexes. I can insert, update and select by "id" but anything more complex (e.g. involving a search in 1 or 2 additional fields or sorting the results) runs into infinity. Example:

`SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE extra = ''`

This query would select entries where "extra" is empty. There is an index on "extra" and

`EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE extra = ''`

tells me it is just a SIMPLE query with the correct index automatically chosen ("Using where; Using index"). If I set a low LIMIT I am fine, selecting thousands of results though and the query never stops running. Using more than 1 field in my search even with a combined index and explicitly adding the name of that index to the query and I'm out of luck as well.

Since there is more than enough storage available on my vServer and MariaDB/InnoDB don't have such low size limits for tables there might be some settings or other limitations that would prevent me from running queries on larger database tables. Looking through all the settings of MariaDB I couldn't find anything appropriate though.

Would be glad if someone could point me into the right direction.

Comment: Please add the table definition of the problematic table (`show create table tablename`) including all indexes, as well as the `explain`-output of all queries you mentioned (and check if a `limit 1000` changes the execution plan). Does "infinity" finally results in a timeout (and if yes, which)? Have you tested if e.g. `limit 200` takes half the time of `limit 400` (but is just much too slow), or do you have a breaking point where `limit 400` is (relatively) fine but `limit 500` doesn't finish in twice the time?

Comment: For such a large number of rows, you'll need to optimize every search separately. That entails creating indexes tailored for each query. Please add to your question the specific queries you want to optimize.

Comment: Less hand-waving; more specifics.

Comment: What is the average length of the JSON column?